# MVC Reset the ModelState so error messages don't show

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The index of my home page displays a lot of data and also includes a submit form. The form works great... except... the validation errors are always present.

[image]

When the user successfully submits the form and passes the ModelState.IsValid method I redirect them back to the Index (entry point) action method. At this point I want all validation to not display. They just submitted so why display errors at this point? See the code below (highlighted section shows my current attempt to remove the validation.

[image]

When the user first enters the screen there are no validation messages (good), but after the first submit they never go away again.

How can I get validation to stop once I redirect back to Index()? Thanks.
EDIT:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new PublicationModel(PublicationRepository.Instance.GetAllPublications().OrderBy(p => p.pname).ToList());

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PublicationSubmitItem model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Send an email
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var parentModel = new PublicationModel(PublicationRepository.Instance.GetAllPublications().OrderBy(p => p.pname).ToList());
        parentModel.SubmitItem = model;

        return View(parentModel);
    }
```

```html
<section id="pubform">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Id)*@

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedPublications, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SelectedPublications, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedPublications, "You must pick at least 1 publication.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control medium-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "A name is required.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control medium-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "An email address is required.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control short-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationId, new SelectList(Model.Locations, "Id", "Name"))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Extension, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Extension, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control short-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Extension, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #DAEAF5;" />
                    <input type="button" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #DAEAF5;" id="clearButton" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
        
    }
</section>
```

The form always displays validation errors.

@ataravati - I redirect to index because I want to reshow the same page they were just on. The form will reset and the data will be the same - this is wanted behavior. The form actually sends an email, it shouldn't redirect them to a different page.

EDIT2 - I figured out that if I remove my custom error messages the form works as expected. Now to figure out why/how to get around it.

Comment: Show your code, not an image of it. Validation messages will NOT be displayed when you redirect to `Index()`. Your methods does not have a model as a parameter so there is nothing added to `ModelState`. If you are seeing those errors it because your returning the view, not redirecting (you never enter your `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block)

Comment: Why are you redirecting to Index when the ModelState is valid?

Comment: Actually it seems validation errors are ALWAYS displayed, even if I stop the app and open the home page for the first time. I'll update with some code.

Comment: They are displayed because you have specified them to be using the 2nd parameter of `ValidationMessageFor()`. It should be `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I just realized the same thing. Now to figure out how to display my custom messages instead. Please comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specifying the error to be displayed using the 2nd parameter of `ValidationMessageFor()`. Instead, use

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

and the set the error message text using the data annotations on your properties

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A name is required.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```